# Give rights to a sub map on my domain?

Tags: security, ftp, domain, www

Is it possible to safely give other people FTP rights to one or more sub-maps within my domain?

I want people that know how to work with FTP clients directly upload to my domain instead of using my uploading scripts and coding on the website. So I'm looking for a safe way to grant them access to one or more sub-maps but certainly keep them out of others.

Currently I tried to make a FTP user account and grant that account only access to a sub map. But logging in with this account puts me in the root where you can see all my files and maps there, since it is a "sub-sub-map" I cannot access anything either. If I put the complete path to this map as host in filezilla, it fails to connect.

-edit-
I suddenly was able to get into the right map when I tried to login after half an hour or so with the newly made account. It brought me to the map the user was assigned too. So, I changed it again, and it still brings me to the map it previously was assigned too. Can it be delayed somehow?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But what tools are you currently using?

Comment: Up until now just the control panel of my host and PHP myadmin. I am using this host, sorry it's in dutch but the tools available should be clear. https://www.sohosted.com/webhosting, i apologies if this is spam.

Comment: However, in the end i want to create a map and a user for it once someone registers his account if possible. But for functionality sake i just need to put up some maps and users.